# How Can I consume this Json using React-Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

i'd like to know how can I use and consume this json, showing and updading always the list, please i need this for my work and i am struggling to make it.

[HERE THE JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Za5Hs.png)

Comment: Don't post a screenshot of code... put it here.

Comment: Show us what you've tried and we may be able to help but as it currently stands... it's quite unclear what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just like in React. First you should fetch the data(usually `componentDidMount()` is a good place for that. You need to update your component's state to contain the fetched data. Here is an example using `axios`, but the same effect can be achieved with `fetch` API.

```js
class MyComponent extends Component {
    state = {
        data : []
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        axios.get('myendpoint')
              .then(res => this.setState({data : res}))
    }

    render(){
        const { data } = this.state

        return(
            <FlatList
                data={data}
                renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item}</Text>}
            />
        )
    }

}
```

With `fetch`

```js
class MyComponentWithFetch extends Component {
    state = {
        data : []
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        fetch('myendpoint')
            .then(docs => docs.json())
            .then(res => this.setState({data : res}))
    }

    render(){
        const { data } = this.state

        return(
            <FlatList
                data={data}
                renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item}</Text>}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

ps: Don't forget the keys

Comment: i am not following...  data.map is not a method for react-native, and i am getting several errors, how can i use a flatlist? please

Comment: `map` is an array/object built-in javascript function, so will work everywhere on javascript. The map method expect a collection as an argument and a callback function that will be called in every single item. I'm using in my example to generate multiples list items, similar to Flatlist's renderItem. I will update my example to flatlist